# 2.8 UI missing all menus, cannot interact with Blender at all

Tags: interface

I'm on Win10 at work, purged everything Blender related from my PC, all files, cache, settings, registry, everything. Updated Nvidia drivers. Still getting this weird issue on a fresh 2.8 (official) install that 90% of my UI is not there and I cannot interact with the program at all. Any ideas what could possibly cause this? A few days ago this was still working fine :\

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if your hardware fulfills the minimum requirements to run Blender 2.8 (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/)? In case it does, open Blender's installation directory and double click on `blender_factory_startup.cmd`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: thanks for your tips, I found the solution and posted an answer

Answer (score 3):

Ok so apparently something got messed up with the PYTHONPATH environment variable and Blender wasn't able to properly locate the python modules it needs to run. After fixing the environment variables, Blender is running fine again. Crazy stuff

Comment: Hi, would be good if you could add information as to *what* you actually did to fix the environment variables, just for people who may have the same problem in future.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the PYTHONPATH environment variable being set to something outside the scope of blender it seems. If you make a bat file with:

```
set PYTHONPATH=
blender
```

Place this in the same place as the blender.exe and then run it.

This will bypass the system environment variable and should load as intended.