# Blender 3.6 menus missing and interface unresponsive after fresh install

Tags: python, interface, error

I have installed 3.6 for the first time but the interface remains mostly empty and is completely unresponsive to input. There are no errors shown upon launch and the only thing i'm able to do is closing the splash screen. After that i'm left with the interface as shown in the screenshot.

[image: Empty unresponsive blender interface]

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem? I'm on Windows 10 and i've worked with Blender on this machine up until 2.8 came out. I suspect it may be a python thing, but as I see no errors i'm clueless.

Thanks.

Comment: What does it show if you start Blender by double-clicking the 'blender_debug_log.cmd' file in the Blender executable folder? (You may not see the .cmd extension if you don't have file name extension visibility enabled.)

Comment: Strange, when opened with the blender_debug_log.cmd everything works normal, the interface is back and there are no errors. Still won't function normally when executing the main application executable.

Comment: Does it show any errors at all if you open the log that it produces with a text editor?

Comment: No, not a single error in the blender_debug_output.txt

Comment: No idea in that case, I'm afraid. There are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation so I can only suggest using Help > Report a Bug in Blender. I'm not sure how anyone at Blender is going to be able to help though unless someone else has already reported the same problem. Incidentally, Blender has its own built-in version of python so it's unlikely that will be the problem.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152450/2-8-ui-missing-all-menus-cannot-interact-with-blender-at-all?rq=1  See the second answer there. That Set PYTHONPATH= line is actually in the 3.6 debug_log.cmd file so presumably that's why it is working correctly when you run Blender via the debug file. Doesn't answer why it's happening in the first place, but at least it will get you running without creating log files every time!